# Django admin: exclude values from dropdown while keeping existing value

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a site with conference rankings, where FoR codes are one of the fields. The database includes old FoR codes that are no longer used. I'd like to exclude these codes from the dropdown menu of the change form on the admin site, as it takes some scrolling to reach the current codes ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWzye.png)).

I tried excluding the old codes by overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey`, as seen in the below code snippet. However, if a conference entry with an old code is opened in the admin site, then the FoR code dropdown is cleared ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EHkx.png)).

Is it possible to exclude the old FoR codes while still preserving the FoR code for old entries? In the example I linked above ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWzye.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EHkx.png)), I want to preserve the 0905 code for this old entry, while only showing the current codes for new entries.

```py
#admin.py
class RankInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Rank
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "for":
            kwargs["queryset"] = ForCode.objects.filter(code__startswith="46")
        return super(RankInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    
    
class CommentInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    extra = 0


class ConferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("acronym", "title", "url")
    list_display_links = ("acronym", "title", "url")
    search_fields = ("acronym", "title", "url")
    inlines = (RankInline, CommentInLine)
```

```py
#models.py
class ForCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Rank(models.Model):
    conference = models.ForeignKey(Conference, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    for_code = models.ForeignKey(ForCode, db_column="for", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: So you only want to then include 905 if that was selected, or in case an old one was selected, include *all* items?

Comment: Can you also include your `Conference`, `Rank` and `ForCode` model (the `ForeignKey`, etc. will likely do).

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Either way would be helpful, though I think just including the selected code (0905 in this case) would be better. I've added the code for the relevant models.